# Angular HPM localhost error from while trying to proxy request /api/books from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:3333

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, proxy

Been trying for a few hours to get this issue fixed but cant make a post request with this error. At first i was using ng serve but then started using npm start but still got errors.

Error:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/books from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:3333 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

My proxy file:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://localhost:4200",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65575397/217408 seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Is this issue with NX Monorepo ? If yes, you are just running this command :

```
ng serve
```

In a new tab of terminal, also run the command :

```
ng serve api
```

Since both servers need to be started.

Answer (score -1):

port 4200 is your app running on, isn't it?
so then you have to change target url in proxy file to localhost:3300.

Comment: why are you using https?

Comment: I tried http too. Does placing the proxy config file in the root matter?

Comment: yes, put proxy file in root (same level in package.json) and run ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json

Comment: I fixed it, since i am running NX monorepo i have to do ng serve api in a new terminal